# How to make a lamp light only one object in the scene

Tags: rendering, light, collections, layers

I'm new to blender, and I'm a hard time understanding layers and collections.
I started using Blender on 2.8, and most of the topics I read about the matter compare how it works now with how it used to work. I know I can do this by using layers and collections but I would really appreciate a step by step guide.

This is my scene:[image]

There is a background, a shirt, and a backlight between them, to light the shirt. I want this area light to affect only the shirt, and not the background. But I do want the background to be affected by everything else (shadows, other lamps and such). How should I proceed?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will have to create separate layers for each render,
elements that you want to be effected separately put them in different collection.
[image]

Basically you can create the whole scene and then duplicate the render layer, in one of them disable the view layer (right-click on the collection --> View Layer --> Disable from View Layer.)
Do the opposite on the other render layer.

[image]

Use the compositor to stitch the images together using Alpha Over node.
[image]

attaching a .blend file for you to review.

[image]

Comment: I kinda got it... but what if I want the shirt to still cast shadow over the background?

Comment: @AndréLuizGollo Maybe try to create another layer with a background plane 'shadow catcher'
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EBoiG6jw6MU

Comment: I got it now! I duplicated the shirt and disabled its camera visibility. :) Thanks guys!!

Comment: That's actually easier ;) nice work

Comment: The answer is very dense in content (for beginners like me). Keep in mind that you need to have two different rendering layers (not two different scenes). It is written in the answer but took me while to figure it out.

Comment: Thanks, `Alpha Over` did the trick (else you will get some transparencies on each individual layer, even with opac object).